# Azure functions experimental templates

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to use Azure functions and I see that there are Sample and Experimental type of templates. 
Can I trust experimental templates in production environment?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, experimental templates are for languages and/or features which are still in preview (e.g. features like external files and any language other than C#, F#, or Node).

It's possible that there could be significant breaking changes introduced for these preview languages and features. However, you are able to decide whether or not to upgrade your functions runtime to the newer version, so the old version should still work in production.